# Hide the nav on First Panel - PanelSnap Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the PanelSnap plugin by guidobouman for my website. But I would like to tweak it a bit to create the desired effect. I would like to hide the navigation on the first panel and display on the others.

http://jsfiddle.net/NDkZz/

This is the code I'm using now:

CSS

```
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }

  body {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 32px;
  }

  h1 {
    font-weight: inherit;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 250%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  a {
    color: inherit;
  }

  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  p {
    max-width: 800px;
  }

  p.small,
  pre {
    font-size: 70%;
  }

  section {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #1abc9c;
  }

  section:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #16a085;
  }

  section section {
    background: #f1c40f;
  }

  section section:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #f39c12;
  }

  section pre {
    background: #16a085;
  }

  section:nth-child(2n) pre {
    background: #1abc9c;
  }

  .panels {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
  }


  .menu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    background: #0ff3ec;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  }

  .menu a.active,
  .menu a:active,
  .menu a:hover {
    background: #1195f3;
  }
```

HTML

```
<section class="menu_demo">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="" data-panel="first">
      First panel
    </a>
    <a href="" data-panel="second" class="active">
      Second panel
    </a>
    <a href="" data-panel="third">
      Third panel
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="panels">
    <section data-panel="first">
      <h1>First</h1>
    </section>
    <section style="background-color: black;" data-panel="second">
      <h1>Second</h1>
    </section>
    <section data-panel="third">
      <h1>Third</h1>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/jquery.customEvents.js"></script>
<script src="http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/jquery.panelSnap.js"></script>
<script>
  // Basic demo
  $('body').panelSnap();

  // Menu demo
  $('.menu_demo .panels').panelSnap({
    $menu: $('.menu_demo .menu')
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you intend to hide the "First Panel"/"Second Panel"/"Third Panel" links when they click on the "First Panel" link (if so, how will they see the menu again?)  But if so, this should do the trick:

```
$('.menu a').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-panel') == 'first'){
        $('.menu').hide();
    } else {
        $('.menu').show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NDkZz/1/

Comment: Thank you for the answser Leonardo. But it doesn't work as it should. When you click the first panel, the menu disappears. Which is good. But when you scroll from Panel 1 to the other panels. The menu will not display.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by passing a function to `onSnapStart` in the options:

```
$('.menu_demo .panels').panelSnap({
    $menu: $('.menu_demo .menu'),
    onSnapStart: function($target) {
        if($target.find('h1').text() === "First") {
            //hide menu
        } else {
            //show menu
        }
    },
});
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/k3gMX/7/) using jQuery's animate function to show and hide the menu.